# Xdebug not working after storage symbolic link - Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I have worked on few Laravel projects. I use PhpStorm as my IDE which I setup to work with Xdebug.

This is the first time I have used Laravel symbolic link to create a link between `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` directory.

After this my Xdebug stops hitting the breakpoint even though my Xdebug seems to be configured as always.

I have tested Xdebug in another Laravel project in PhpStorm and it was working so it is not related to PhpStorm. I opened my current project (one with symbolic link) in IntelliJ IDEA but Xdebug was not working there too so there is something fishy in my project only.

After reading [JetBrains Xdebug troubleshooting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#verify-xdebug-zend-debugger) I came to know that I have to use path mapping in

`Settings |Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`.

Now the problem is I really don't know which path to be mapped to which folder and found no related solution on internet (maybe I'm bad at googling)

Here is my bad attempt:

[image]

I just tried to map storage (in public) directory with public (in storage -> app) directory.

Please guide me regarding this.

**xdebug.log file**

```
[3172] Log opened at 2020-08-25 17:39:58
[3172] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[3172] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[3172] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[3172] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: http://127.0.0.1:8000/:9000. :-|
[3172] W: Creating socket for 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/:9000', getaddrinfo: 0.
[3172] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[3172] Log closed at 2020-08-25 17:39:58

[7416] Log opened at 2020-08-25 17:43:53
[7416] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[7416] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[7416] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7416] I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
[7416] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[7416] Log closed at 2020-08-25 17:43:53
```

Comment: Why does the absolute path on your server contain an IP and a port? Are you really sure this is the path? What happens if you use Run > "Break at first line"?

Comment: actually I don't know which path to put there, I tried putting this `C:\xampp\htdocs\HRMS\public` but no luck. Also `break at first line` is did nothing.

Comment: Xdebug only cares about the absolute path. The absolute path should not include an IP address. So, in your case your mapping for /public/storage should be to `/full/path/to/storage/app/public`, or on Windows: `c:\full\path\to\storage\app\public`

Comment: This is my full path to `C:/xampp/htdocs/HRMS/storage/app/public`. even this doesn't work.

Comment: If "Break at first line" is not working, then you are doing something wrong. What have you tried to check whether XDebug is enabled?

Comment: My Xdebug always works. it only stops hitting breakpoint after I used laravel symbolic link. I doubt that path mapping is the problem but doesn't have enough understanding to resolve it. still digging around.

Comment: It's not shown on the screenshot nor it's stated in the question, so - did you open the project directly from the web root in PhpStorm?
Meaning, what project path do you see [here](https://prnt.sc/u5hdge)?

Comment: Make a log file (see https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log), and see what it does with the initial filepath (`fileuri`) and which paths it sets for breakpoints (`breakpoint_set`)

Comment: I see this path`C:\xampp\htdocs\HRMS` @EugeneMorozov

Comment: @Derick I setup log file as `xdebug.remote_log = "C:\xampp\htdocs\xdebug.log"`. After loading page there is no log in the log file. Also there is no clear guide where to put `xdebug.log` file. I put it in htdocs. referred [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-Xdebug)

Comment: I found something in log file and updated my question with the log

Comment: 1. You need no debug mappings since you open the project directly from the web root.  Uncheck the `Use path mappings` checkbox. 2. Your `xdebug.remote_host` parameter value is wrong, it's supposed to be just `localhost` in your case

Comment: I unchecked the path mapping and set `xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"` but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Path mappings are indeed the answer.

Instead of putting a mapping on the location of the symlink (`public/storage`) you need to put the mapping on the target of the symlink (`storage/app/public`). This needs to be mapped to the absolute path on the server (which you identify as `C:/xampp/htdocs/HRMS/storage/app/public`).

This is made somewhat easier if you can put a break point on a line which calls a script within the symlinked directory. When you hit that break point then "step into" the called function PHP Storm will complain that

> remote path `<something>` is not mapped to
> any file path in project
>
> Click to set up path mappings

Click on that, find the storage/app/public directory in your project files and type in the `<something>` from the debugger message. Hit OK, and all should be good.